# My ComboBox doesn't display the values I've added in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I'm trying to add options to a combo box in a userform. When I run the code, Excel doesn't give any errors, however when the userform shows up it doesn't display the entities I have added to the combobox previously. That is, when I click on the combobox, it doesn't show any options, only one blank row, as if no items were added to it.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "xxx"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "yyy"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "zzz"
End Sub
```

I am using the following code to call the user form within a macro:

```
UserForm.Show
```

Comment: Where is the `UserForm_Initilize()` code pasted? It has to be in the userform

Comment: I believe the userform doesnt necessarily initialize every time you load it- if youre showing and hiding it more than once then the initialize code should only run once.  Try adding a breakpoint to that code to see if it's actually running?

Comment: *Code is in the userform
*I don't think the code is running properly Acantud, it still works when I disable the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given in the question works perfectly well. In my case the code didn't work because I manually entered this part of the code into VBA:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

If you make Excel create this module for you instead of writing it on your own, your code should work perfectly. Excel did not have "Initialize" as a default form so I tried "Activate" and it worked.

To create this module you have to do the following steps:

1. Right click on user form
2. Click on view code
3. On top you will see two categories you can pick, you should pick "Userform" and "Activate", after completing this step excel must add a new module to your code.
4. In this module you may code everything you want about the content of the combobox.

You should also be careful with the spelling of your combobox, if you spell it incorrectly, you may be unable to see the contents of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the code segment you have posted is in the userform.

Right click on the user form in the VBA view and choose "View Code". Is this where the code is?

Are you sure that the User Form is called 'UserForm' and not 'UserForm1'? 'UserForm1' is the default, similar to 'ComboBox1'.

The below works for me.

```
'in the UserForm1 code
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.AddItem "xxx"
ComboBox1.AddItem "yyy"
ComboBox1.AddItem "zzz"
End Sub
```

The below will display the form.

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Is this the only form in the workbook? Create a new one and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: I did it exactly the way you described it but it still does not work. 
I also have the name of the user form correct.

Comment: Above code should work. Is this the only form in the workbook? Create a new one and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think I found the couse of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but I solved setting ColumnWidths property to -1 (it was set to 0).